# Perform action before form submit?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this HTML form with an id and I have binded this id to the submit function. What I want is when a user clicks submit, a popup comes up like a modal box thanking them.  And only after they click off the screen or when the modal box closes is when I want the form to submit and refresh the page.

But the way I have it now seems it will refresh no matter what.  I am using the fancy popup plugin for the modal box.

```
<form action="submit-comment.php" method="post" id="form">
<input type="text" name="comment" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

jQuery("#form").submit(function() {
     jQuery.fancybox('<div class="box">Some content</div>', {
           'onClosed' : function() { return true; }
            }     
     });
});
```

As you can see I am trying to tell it to return true only on close but it isn't really working.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's very dangerous functionality. If a user submits a form and see a thank you message, he/she would expect that the data was already submitted and may simply close the window or tab, having not actually submitted anything. I fully advise you submit the data first and then show an appropriate message (thank you for success or an error for failure) based on the returned response.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#form").submit(function(e) {
     var self = this;
     e.preventDefault();
     jQuery.fancybox('<div class="box">Some amazing wonderful content</div>', {
           'onClosed' : function() { 
                          self.submit();
                        }
     });
     return false; //is superfluous, but I put it here as a fallback
});
```

javascript is asynchronous so you cannot delay the return statement.

---

**UPDATE**

To make it so that the code above works, change the `name` of you submit button to something else, for example:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_me" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: @lonesomeday, I just usually have it there as a fallback for the `preventdefault`

Comment: @lonesomeday - just what I was going to say. (+1 from me too Neal)

Comment: @Neal But jQuery makes that unnecessary, and you're preventing propagation where you don't really want to...

Comment: @lonesomeday, i added a comment about it in my answer

Comment: Surely this enters an eternal loop? You're binding an event to the form and simply recalling that event?

Comment: @amustill, where do you see a loop??

Comment: @amustill, `self.subit()` is calling the native DOM submit action. if i did `$(self).submit()` then i'd be in trouble with an infinite loop

Comment: @Neal - thanks for that but I am getting an error "self.submit" is not a function?

Comment: @rick, change the name of your submit button: `<input type="submit" name="submit_me" value="Submit" />` fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8d9Qj/2/

Comment: @Rick, then how are you running the js with no access to the html? you can just do `$('[name=submit]').attr('name','something_else')`, which might work

Comment: @Neal - I am trying to understand why the name has to be changed to work?  I don't have access as it is a comment file create by Wordpress and I am trying not to have to do too much work to use custom template if I can get away with it.

Comment: @Neal - Hi Neal sorry to bother you but I just realize this doesn't work in IE...the self.submit() is causing problems for IE..

Answer (score 2):

*(response to Rick's question under Neal's answer: "any other way? Because I don't have direct access to this html")*

If you, for some reason, need a submit button to have ID="submit" and cannot use form.submit method (because it links to "input[type=submit]#submit" button) you can do this:

```
$('<form>')[0].submit.call(form); //jQuery
//OR:
document.createElement('form').submit.call(form); //pure HTML w/o any framework
```

i.e. create new empty form and use its submit method to call it in scope of your own form