# Dynamically changed action in HTML form with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to change the action of a form using jQuery. Sounds simple. This is what I have:

*mypage.html*

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="fake" onsubmit="changeAction()">
<!-- Several fields here -->
</form>
```

*mypage.js*

```
function changeAction()
{
    $('#myform').submit(function () {
        // Dynamically builds action
        var action = '/some/url/based/on/dynamic/content';
        $('#myform').attr('action', action);
    });
}
```

My problem is **the action called is always *fake***, the default action I put in the form. I've tried several options, like `get(0).setAttribute` instead of `attr`, but nothing seems to work. Using **jQuery 1.10.2**, if helps.

**How could I dynamically change the form action just before submitting it?**

Comment: What about moving the `.attr` call before you call `submit()`.  Is it maybe too late by that point?

Comment: do you use (only) a button to submit the form? or pressing enter key submits the form also?

Comment: Maybe you can make use of this trick, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103077/perform-action-before-form-submit

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I already have the answer to the problem. See @Guffa response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code that you run from the submit event doesn't change the action, it only binds an event that would change the action if the form is submitted again.

Change the action in the function instead of binding an event:

```
function changeAction() {
    // Dynamically builds action
    var action = '/some/url/based/on/dynamic/content';
    $('#myform').attr('action', action);
}
```